# explorer.exe becoming unkillable and wasting CPU cycles shortly after boot

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, process

I'm on Windows 10 21H1, Build 19043.1110.

I first noticed this problem yesterday. Every time Windows boots, it takes around 20 seconds for explorer.exe to become unkillable while wasting CPU cycles on nothing.

[image: Screenshot of explorer.exe's Task Manager entry]

Hitting End Task in taskmgr does literally nothing. Hitting End Task spits out this error message:

[image: Screenshot of a message box saying "The operation could not be completed. Access is denied."]

Running `taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F` yields this unhelpful message:

```
> taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
ERROR: The process "explorer.exe" with PID 17652 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
```

I saw people online mention Process Explorer, which also can't kill it. I ran `sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` for good measure, and while sfc claimed to actually have repaired something, it didn't fix this issue. As always, there's nothing in the event logs about any of this.

What's happening? Is this a known problem? How do I get the explorer to stop doing this?

Comment: See if you have the same issue in a different User Profile. If so, then do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: You only see that entry in Task Scheduler when you've opened a folder. All I can think is it's a zombie process. That a program that has exited but another program took a handle too it so it's has to hang about for the other program (so it remains a valid handle for the other program). Using the `wmic process get executablepath, processid, parentprocessid /format:csv` identify it parent process.

Comment: Also use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns and disable all items on the Explorer tab and reboot.

Comment: I tried a partial reinstall, but that didn't help. It took a full disk wipe and reinstall for the problem to go away.